# How to disable shutdown option in KDE 4/5

Tags: kde, shutdown

I want to know if there is a way to supress shutdown option for KDE 4/5. Reboot option is fine. 
Users of remote VMs tend to shut down VMs by mistake and that results in a lot of support calls ;).

Regards.